# If addProximityAlert expiration is -1, will it removeProximityAlert after it is triggered?

Tags: android, proximity

If `addProximityAlert` expiration is -1, will it cancel after it is triggered? Or are you required to `removeProximityAlert` in ENTERING or EXITING if you want to remove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if expiration is -1, then it will never expire. Even after being triggered. You will need to use removeProximityAlert to remove it.